# How do I open a terminal window with C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I recently decided to start teaching myself C++ and thought a simple encryption project would be a good place to start, since it covers most of the basics (cout, cin, opening files, etc). Is there a way to have the code open a terminal window similar to the one opened when I compile and run from sublime text?

I have tried this so far, but it hasn't changed anything.

```
    string cmd = "gnome-terminal-x sh-c 'ls-l; exec bash'";
    system(cmd.c_str());
```

Essentially, I would like to be able to run the program by clicking the .exe, and have the terminal where all of the input and output goes pop up.

Comment: "and thought a simple encryption project would be a good place to start". Just about the worst possible one actually.

Comment: "Is there a way to have the code open a terminal window similar to the one opened when I compile and run from sublime text?" We just don't do that. You want to develop software? Open a terminal. Don't close it. It's your bread, butter, your drinking water, your breathing air, whatever. Type all your commands there. Forget you have a "desktop", except when you need to open more terminals.

Comment: If you want your program to run in a terminal when clicked on, create a desktop file ("shortcut") for it and click "run in terminal" somewhere in advanced properties dialog.

Comment: Proofread your code, do you really have `sh-c` and `ls-l` with no space there?

Comment: @n.m Why would one need a terminal window while developing software? Sure it is one, somewhat archaic, way to work, and necessary when more specialized tools are not available for whatever reason and task, but you talk like it is the only way.

Comment: You should test the result of `system`. You probably want absolute paths in your command (e.g. `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`). You need a space before `-c` and `-l`. And your project won't teach you a lot of C++. Try something else! Perhaps find some free software written in C++ and study its source code. BTW, try first to type your command in a terminal (to get a *working* command) before passing it to `system`

Comment: @hyde It's not the only way, sure. I've tried a few of them, most do work to some extent. I relate what's in my experience the best way (by far).

Comment: What is the question here, actually? Is it, how do I write a program, which works like a Windows console program (a concept for which there is no exact equivalent in Unix)? Is it, how do I launch another program (say, *openssl* command line tool) from my program in a terminal? Is it just, how do I launch any command line program from the desktop or file manager by double-clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write any code, you just need to configure the shortcut to launch the program in a terminal.  Here's a Gnome dialog that shows that option:

[image: Gnome shortcut properties dialog box]

Comment: @hyde: it helps the user get back to the problem at hand, by solving his stated problem.

Comment: Knowing when not to use C++ is an important thing of learning C++.

Comment: Even if you think question is misguided, SO is wrong place to write a piece of Ubuntu howto as an answer. You should at least *also* provide the answer to the actual on-topic programming question, how to do this from code.

Comment: @hyde: Rather than complaining in the comments on my answer, why not write your own, better answer?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I was about to, but was not at a PC when writing those comments. Now I did write an answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be `gnome-terminal`, or then just my failure to give it the right arguments. For example `gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'ls -l ; exec bash'` from command line in another terminal just opens an empty gnome-terminal and spits out a bunch of glib warnings to original terminal... (Note to readers: if you can give the right command that works for `gnome-terminal`, please let me know in comments or just edit this paragraph.)

However, using `xterm` works, for example `xterm -e sh -c 'ls -l; exec bash'`, or a line for your code:

```
string cmd = "xterm -e sh -c 'ls -l; exec bash'";
```

As a side note, the command to open the default x terminal window of the DE is `x-terminal-emulator`, but it quite often has the practical problem of different terminals taking different arguments, so sadly you're probably better of using a specific terminal, like that `xterm`, and requiring that to be installed, or letting user to configure what terminal to use, with what arguments (though letting user to specify any command to be run can also be a security risk, if user is not always trusted).

---

Just be very careful with escaping. For example, when you test the command form command line, and then copy-paste it to C++ string literal, you need to escape every `"` and `\` one more time for C++. If you have trouble with this, check out [C++11 raw strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings).

Escaping becomes extra important if you construct the command string at runtime, and especially if you accept user input and add that to the string. In that case, better search for and use some existing library [like GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html), or sanitize the user input very carefully (ie. just paranoidically reject anything with chars, which may have a special meaning in shell in some context).

---

If you are actually asking, how can my program open a console window *for itself* similar to how Windows console programs behave, and redirect it's own `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` there, as if it was launched from command line, that that is not very easy from the same binary, and it is not commonly done like that in Unix.

If you want a behaviour like that, you could create a desktop shortcut, but more general way is to write a wrapper shell script, which starts your binary in a terminal. What kind of script exactly, depends on how you want it to behave exactly: what will it do with stdio, will it return or wait for program to exit, how do you want it to find the binary, how does it behave when run from command line instead of double-clicking from GUI, etc.

Comment: TS doesn't really want to run `ls` from his program. He wants the standard input and output *of his own program* to go to the newly opened terminal. He is trying to use `sh` and `ls` and stuff not because he actually needs them but because he doesn't know what to use.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the OP actually wants. This answer answers the literal question of the title and the text. The question might be better off closed until clarified, though...

Comment: It is perfectly clear actually. "similar to the one opened when I compile and run from sublime text". There are no two ways to read this.

Comment: "gnome-terminal --command=\"bash -c 'ls -l; exec bash'\"" Seems to work for gnome.terminal.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Doesn't work for me, though I'm running LXDE and not Gnome or Unity. I get just a blank terminal window which does nothing (menus etc work, I mean the actual text area).

Comment: @n.m. I take that to mean, the user is writing a program which is acting like Sublime Text there , and wants that program to open the another program (like Sublime Text opens the compiled program) in  a terminal.

Comment: No, he is writing a hello world program. It runs in a terminal when started by his IDE (SublimeText). He wants it to run in a terminal when started from the desktop too.

Comment: @n.m. Mmm, yes, that kinda makes sense too, in a twisted way. Also, OP is saying ".exe", which indicates Windows background. So maybe he ideed wants equivalent of Windows console program, which automatically gets a console window.